# play framework 2.0 evolutions, how to mark an inconsistent state as resolved in PROD

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have an application developed in scala play2.0,
it worked successfully in local, but if failed when deployed to heroku.

the reason of the fail is that locally i was using a H2 database,
and using postgresql in heroku, i have to change one of the data types from "clob" to "text".

the problem now is that the database in heroku is in a "inconsistent state", according to the play20 documentation.
in DEV mode (locally), you can just click on the "Mark it as resolved" when the html appears.

how to "mark it ask resolved" in the heroku PROD environtment?
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Evolutions

ps: note, because it was a new application, i just deleted the database and re-started.
however, here i am asking what is the proper way to handle evolutions in the PROD env.
that is, the "Mark it as resolved" issue for PROD is not explained here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Evolutions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I couldn't find a way to do it via the `play` command, you can do it by editing the database directly.

Imagine you're trying to go from `5.sql` to `6.sql`. Here's what you do:

1. Figure out and fix the problem(s) that caused the database to enter an inconsistent state (i.e. manually apply your `!Ups` and fix all the problems with them).
2. Manually apply your `!Downs` so that the database is in the state it was after `5.sql` was applied.
3. Go into your database, find the table called `play_evolutions`, and look at the row with id `6`. It should saying something like `applying ups` in the `state` column and have the error message in the `last_problem` column.
4. Delete the row with id `6`. This will make Play think you are in the state you were with `5.sql`.
5. Now you should be able to run `play -DapplyEvolutions.default=true start` to evolve to `6.sql`.

Answer (score -2):

Inconsistent state just means that the evolutions could not be applied and thus, the application is blocked. Update your evolution scripts and re-deploy.

Comment: are you sure about this? it doesn't make sense to me. for me, "inconsistent state" means "inconsistent state", that is, only part of the evolution (sql script) has been executed, and the playframework cannot undo nor finish the evolution, so manual intervention needs to be done to carefully revert or complete the evolution to a consistent state.